# With Pymongo, how do I insert data from a form in the database?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
info = ([request.form['author'], request.form['title'], request.form['text']])  
mongo.db.posts.insert(info, safe=True)
```

but I get a TypeError:'unicode' object does not support item assignment.

That's the last line in the stack trace:

```
if not "_id" in son:
    son["_id"] = ObjectId()
    return son
```

Comment: Which of the two statements is raising the TypeError? Have you tried doing any kind of debugging? Have you attempted to make any sense of the stack trace?

Comment: `son` seems to be a unicode object. Can you give us more context (i.e. more lines of code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Pymongo your document must be a dict, not list.

Try:

```
info = {"author": request.form['author'], "title": request.form['title'], "text": request.form['text']}
```

or:

```
info = {"info": [request.form['author'], request.form['title'], request.form['text']]}
```

whatever is closer to your idea of model.

---

Actually this kind of error is documented for save() and update() methods of collection, but not for insert():

> Raises TypeError if to_save is not an instance of dict.

[pymongo collection docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html)

Comment: I tried something like this but I didn't know what my key was.